# Multiple nested tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to create a table with multiple nested tables, such as this example?

```
create or replace type t_products is object(
    name varchar(20),
    price float(4,2),
    drinks col_drinks,
    foods col_foods
);
/

create table products of t_products nested table drinks, foods store as drink, food;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you need separate `nested table .. store as ...` clauses for them:

```
create table products of t_products
    nested table drinks store as drink,
    nested table foods store as food;
```

Also `float` can't have a scale, but you can use `number` anyway; and `varchar` should be `varchar2`.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4737db59596d2bd99ebf742f29d0f3de)

Comment: Thank you! It was very useful.